# Getting error using Google cloud client libraries for Go: unknown credential type: "impersonated_service_account"?

Tags: go, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am working with Google Cloud in Go and following this article by John Hanley:

https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-improving-security-with-impersonation/

and mashed it with this SO answer:

[How to authenticate Google APIs (Google Drive API) from Google Compute Engine and locally without downloading Service Account credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63506885/how-to-authenticate-google-apis-google-drive-api-from-google-compute-engine-an/63507265#63507265)

The credentials are successfully saved to, "application_default_credentials.json":

Notice: "type": "**impersonated_service_account**"

```
    {
  "delegates": [],
  "service_account_impersonation_url": "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/[sa@example-2021.iam.gserviceaccount.com]:generateAccessToken",
  "source_credentials": {
    "client_id": "...apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "...",
    "refresh_token": "...",
    "type": "authorized_user"
  },
  "type": "impersonated_service_account"
}
```

My code which produces an **unknown credential type: "impersonated_service_account"** error:

```
package main

import (
...
    "cloud.google.com/go/storage"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "google.golang.org/api/docs/v1"
    "google.golang.org/api/drive/v3"
    "google.golang.org/api/impersonate"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
...
)

var Config.GoogleServiceAccount string = "sa@example-2021.iam.gserviceaccount.com"




func main(){
  _ = getTokenAsImpersonator()
}

// From: https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/impersonate#example-CredentialsTokenSource-ServiceAccount
func getTokenAsImpersonator() oauth2.TokenSource {
    ctx := context.Background()

    // Base credentials sourced from ADC or provided client options.
    ts, err := impersonate.CredentialsTokenSource(ctx, impersonate.CredentialsConfig{
        TargetPrincipal: Config.GoogleServiceAccount,
        Scopes:          []string{"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"},
        // Delegates: []string{"bar@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com"},
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return ts
}
```

The '**unknown credential type: "impersonated_service_account"**' error:

```
google: error getting credentials using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable: unknown credential type: "impersonated_service_account"
```

Have I done something wrong or is this a bug?

---

**UPDATE**

Answering John's questions from the comments:

1.

a) What is the value of the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS?

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/x/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
```

b) What command did you use to generate application_default_credentials.json?

```
gcloud auth application-default login --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/accounts.reauth,openid --impersonate-service-account=[sa@example-2021.iam.gserviceaccount.com]


Response:

Credentials saved to file: [/Users/x/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json]
```

c)Which OS and version?

```
MacOS 10.13.6
```

d)gcloud --version?

```
Google Cloud SDK 343.0.0
app-engine-go 
app-engine-python 1.9.91
bq 2.0.69
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
core 2021.05.27
gsutil 4.62
```

2. If you can create a minimum example ...

I have updated the example code above.

Comment: Update your question with these details. a) What is the value of the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`? b) What command did you use to generate `application_default_credentials.json`? c:) Which OS and version? d)`gcloud --version` 2) If you can create a minimum example so that I can reproduce this on my system, I will help you get this working. Time to add new details to my article.

Comment: I'm not seeing any "impersonated_service_account" search results from google, only "impersonate_service_account". Can you possibly share anything about this @JohnHanley? I'm not pretty familiar with the topic but is very interested.

Comment: @NaziA - I have not yet worked on this question. I do believe that `impersonated_service_account` is a credential type stored by the CLI. In most cases, users should not directly access `application_default_credentials.json`. In the SDK `core/credentials/creds.py` is the function `_ConvertCredentialsToADC()` that converts this credential. I plan to start by understanding this function.

Comment: @NaziA - Another important item is `IMPERSONATION_TOKEN_URL = 'https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/{}:generateAccessToken'` The token created by impersonation is the use as authorization to call that URL to fetch a normal Access Token. I learned these details working with Google Workload Identity Federation. Once I tie together impersonation and federation, I should know the low-level details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At some point I had used the CLI to impersonate an account:

```
gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account <service account>
```

Then later on when trying to use the application default credentials command it wraps your credentials with the service account credentials.

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

What you end up with is a file that looks like this:

```json
{
  "delegates": [],
  "service_account_impersonation_url": "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/example@example-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken",
  "source_credentials": {
    "client_id": "123abc.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "refresh_token": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "type": "authorized_user"
  },
  "type": "impersonated_service_account"
}
```

This appears to cause a lot of problems with third party services such as terraform.

> What is strange is that Terraform is just making API calls to Google using Google SDKs, so really its something to do with Google.

You need to remove the impersonation:

```
gcloud config unset auth/impersonate_service_account
```

And then run the application default credential command again:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Now if you check your file it should look like this:

```json
{
  "client_id": "XXXXXXXXX",
  "client_secret": "XXXXXXXXX",
  "quota_project_id": "example-project",
  "refresh_token": "XXXXXXXXXX",
  "type": "authorized_user"
}
```

I was hitting the same issue when I was trying to impersonate an account so I could run Terraform commands as a service account instead of my personal account but it doesn't like that.

EDIT: Rereading you question it sounds like you're in the same boat as me. We want to use service accounts without physically downloading the keys. This is even mentioned by Google as best practice. But doing so is causing issues with their own SDKs.

Comment: Thanks for this nicely written solution.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't actually solve the issue of why impersonating a service account isn't working, but it will get you back to square one so you can re-use your user account and try a different approach. In the end I had to download the key for the service account which I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue running GCP Terraform provider tests. You can specify the Service Account Terraform have to impersonate setting the env variable `GOOGLE_IMPERSONATE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT` ([documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#full-reference)).

Configuration steps:

- `export GOOGLE_IMPERSONATE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT=SERVICE_ACCOUNT@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
- `gcloud auth application-default login`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30788784)