# terraform unknown credential type: "impersonated_service_account"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, impersonation, service-accounts, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to run a `terraform init` command as an impersonated service account, but am getting the following error and can't figure out a way around it:

```
Error: google: error getting credentials using well-known file (/Users/fakeuser/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json): unknown credential type: "impersonated_service_account"`
```

Before terraform init, I'm running the following commands:

```
gcloud auth application-default login

export GOOGLE_IMPERSONATE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT=gitlab-runner-service-account@fake-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

My application_default_credentials.json file has the following content:

```
{
  "delegates": [],
  "service_account_impersonation_url": "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/gitlab-runner-service-account@fake-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken",
  "source_credentials": {
    "client_id": "replaced.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "replaced",
    "refresh_token": "replaced",
    "type": "authorized_user"
  },
  "type": "impersonated_service_account"
}
```

My terraform block is defined as follows:

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "fake-project-tfstate-bucket"
    prefix = "state/fake-project"
  }
}
```

Terraform v1.3.2. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's curious that your `application_default_credentials.json` has `"type": "impersonated_service_account"`. Usually, the file contains only the value that's embedded as the value of `source_credentials`. Can you try `gcloud auth application-default revoke` (or just delete `application_default_credentials.json`, then reauthenticate `gcloud auth application-default login` and try `terraform init` again?

Comment: Can you try to use that command instead: `gcloud auth application-default login --impersonated-service-account=XXX`, and remove your env var?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! If I run a revoke, login and init as suggested by above, that works. But I'm no longer using the service account in that case so not what I need to do.


If I remove the env var and run the gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account= command, that produces the same error from my original problem. The content of the json file is the same after doing that as well.

Comment: The only other thread I can find online discussing this same problem is:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67927689/getting-error-using-google-cloud-client-libraries-for-go-unknown-credential-typ

But there was no solution there. I'm beginning to think this may be a bug with terraform and not something I can fix myself.

Comment: You **are** still using the Service Account. Per the [Terraform instructions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/using-google-cloud-service-account-impersonation-your-terraform-code), you `export GOOGLE_IMPERSONATE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT` (which will persist across `gcloud auth application-default revoke|login`. The purpose of having you `revoke` and then `login `against was to reset your "unconventionallly" configured `application_default_credentials.json` which originated the error.

Comment: You're right! I just assumed since I was no longer seeing the service account in a `gcloud auth list` command, then I wasn't using it. So your original suggestion looks like it solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Now back to trying to figure out why it's failing in my gitlab pipeline. This exercise was just an attempt to verify my service account would work with terraform :)